# Need help finding common values

Tags: vb.net, listbox, label

Basically what I'm trying to do is pull the most common value out of a listbox. The listbox will have many different randomly generated numbers and it should pull the most common one and highlight it. I can't figure out the proper code and I've tried everything! Please help! (vb.net)

```
Private Sub Check()

    If ListBox1.Items.IndexOf("1") > ListBox1.Items.IndexOf("2") Then

        Label7.Text = "1"
        ListBox1.SelectedItem = ("1")
    Else
        Label7.Text = "2"
        ListBox1.SelectedItem = ("2")

    End If
End Sub
```

In the example above it should check for which value is most common, 1 or 2. then change the label and highlight the number in the listbox. I cant get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim foundMost As String = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String) _
                                        .GroupBy(Function(x) x) _
                                        .OrderByDescending(Function(y) y.Count) _
                                        .First.Key

Label7.Text = foundMost
ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Clear()
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
  If ListBox1.Items(i) = foundMost Then
    ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Add(i)
  End If
Next
```

The LINQ statement above is going through the list of strings in the ListBox and grouping them by their value, then it orders them in descending fashion by how many times that item appeared in the list, then it grabs the first item in the resulting list.